# How to Re-balance Storm Trident Topology

Tags: apache-storm, trident

From  [this](https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Understanding-the-parallelism-of-a-Storm-topology.html) documentation link I could learn that re-balancing a topology is easy with below command

```
storm rebalance mytopology -n 5 -e blue-spout=3 -e yellow-bolt=10
```

But how do I re-balance  a trident topology as in trident topology we can't  label filters/Functions(bolts) with name, So how can I increase/decrease parallelism count ?   Or Is there a way to increase/decrease parallelism count using multiplier for all components in a specific topology ?

Answer (score 2):

Let me answer my own questions;

In case of Trident spouts and bolts are automatically named and the names are b-0,b-1,b-2. This stands for Blot-1 and Bolt-2. These name can be figured out in the Storm UI for a deployed topology

Now using these bolts names we can rebalance a deployed topology.

```
storm rebalance mytopology -n 5 -e b-0=3 -e b-1=10
```

**NOTE:** You can also name a bolt while creating a Trident Topology

eg;

```
 topology.newStream("spout", spout)
         .each(new Fields("sentence"), new Split(), new Fields("word"))
         .shuffle()
         .name("BOLT-NAME")
```